# Display span title on hover on ellipsis

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC5 and I have an ellipsis for a span in my view for which I want to display the title when I hover over it. The truncated value/text of span will display only after choosing any checkbox from the list of options. I have done following so far; but i am having hard time to get title in my view `title="???"`.

```
<div>
    <span>PAYMENT TYPE: </span>
    <span id="payment-sum" title="???"></span>
</div>

function setPayment() {
    var sum = $('input[name=payment-option]:checked').parents('.lbl-option').text().trim();     
    $('#payment-sum').text(sum);
    $('#payment-sum').attr(sum);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do something like this to get the title in the span:

```
$('#payment-summary').attr("title", summary);
```

Let me know if that helps you!

Comment: Yes, it did. Thank you.

Comment: @toofaced awesome! can you accept the answer as correct please